# reading firebase database with an onCreate()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a `database().ref(...).onCreate( event => {..})` as on `firebase cloud functions` but for a normal data read in my reactJS app. I need to wait for another cloud function to execute his code and write the answer in the `.ref(...)` path I'm waiting, so after it finishes, I can now read that info.

I'm getting this error: `database.ref(...).onCreate is not a function`. I can't make a new function for that purpose because I need the callback I get in a query I do inside the `..OnCreate( event => {..})`

Thought on creating a Wait function, and hold the process for 2 seconds so the cloud function should have enough time to run.

Any other thought?
Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that `ref.OnCreate()`, as the error implies, is not actually a function as part of the spec, right? Are you thinking of `ref.on()`? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference

Comment: the problem with `ref.on()` reads the data right away.. I need it to read after the creation

Comment: If there is no value yet the callback will return with `null` and then with the updated value whenever it changes after that. I fail to see how this isn't suited to your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps thinking of the cloud function database trigger? If so, onCreate is a great listener! Here's a great use case that will listen for new nodes being created (onCreate!) at a specified node in the db:

```
exports.EXAMPLE = functions.database.ref('database/{deep}/{link}').onCreate(event => {
  //event.data.val() is your created data
  //event.params.deep and event.data.link are your url wildcard params
})
```

Remember, these are cloud functions; i.e. uploaded to run on firebase servers and 'listen' for triggers. In this case, the trigger is a 'create' event at a specified database node. Other database triggers include onWrite, onUpdate, and onDelete ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)). There are also other great triggers as well, including Cloud Storage events, Authentication events, HTTPS triggers, and more.